# If $[\tau(\ell)\ell]'>0$ what can you say about $\tau$?

Tags: geometry, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, metric-spaces

More specifically, from this paper [http://www4.math.sci.osaka-u.ac.jp/~sohta/papers/mcp.pdf](http://www4.math.sci.osaka-u.ac.jp/%7Esohta/papers/mcp.pdf) , Lemma 4.1, end of page 9, start of page 10:

- Let $\tau:(r,r')\rightarrow(0,1]$ be a $C^1$ function such that $[\tau(\ell)\ell]'>0$ for all $\ell\in(r,r')$, $0\leq r<r'\leq\infty$. In general which properties can $\tau$ have if it satisfies that differential inequalities?

Why that question: let $W\subset X$ be measurable, where $(X,d,\mathfrak{m})$ is a length, geodesic and proper metric measure space ($\mathfrak{m}$ Borel measure). Let $\Gamma$ denote the set of geodesic along which the optimal transportation between any point mass $\delta_x$ and $m$ concentrated on any set of finite $\mathfrak{m}$-measure is performed. Let $e_t:\Gamma\rightarrow X$ denote the evaulation map $e_t(\gamma)=\gamma(t)$ (by $e_\tau(\gamma)$ it means $e_{\tau(Length(\gamma))}(\gamma)$. Partition the space $X$ in annuli centered at $x$: take a large $M\in\mathbb{N}$, set $\delta:=(r'-r)/M$ and $r_m:=r+m\delta$ for $0\leq m\leq M$. Define$$\Gamma_m:=e^{-1}_\tau(W)\cap\{\gamma\in\Gamma\mid e_0(\gamma)=x,e_1(\gamma)\in A(x;r_{m-1},r_m)\}\quad\mbox{and}\quad W_m:=e_\tau(\Gamma_m), 1\leq m\leq M.$$
Then from the hypothesis in $\tau$ is follows that $W_m\cap W_{m'}=\emptyset$ if $m\neq m'$.

- So my question is: which role plays $\tau$ into getting that the intersection between the $W_m$'s is empty, since to me the sets seem disjoint regardless?

(that's why I am asking which properties $\tau$ has since it may follow from that. If we assume that $[\tau(\ell)\ell]'\leq0$ it follows that $\tau$ is strictly decreasing but I do not see a problem with that)